# How to set correct image dimensions by LatLngBounds using ImageOverlay?

Tags: leaflet

I want to use ImageOverlays as markers, because I want the images to scale with zoom. Markers icons always resize to keep their size the same when you zoom.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to transform pixels to cords, so my image isn't stretched.

For instance, I decided my south-west LatLng to be [50, 50]. My image dimensions are 24px/24px.

How do I calculate the north-east LatLng based on the image pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [map conversion methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-conversion-methods).

In particular, you could use:

- [`latLngToContainerPoint`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint): Given a geographical coordinate, returns the corresponding pixel coordinate relative to the map container.
- [`containerPointToLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-containerpointtolatlng): Given a pixel coordinate relative to the map container, returns the corresponding geographical coordinate (for the current zoom level).

```js
// 1) Convert LatLng into container pixel position.
var originPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(originLatLng);
// 2) Add the image pixel dimensions.
// Positive x to go right (East).
// Negative y to go up (North).
var nextCornerPoint = originPoint.add({x: 24, y: -24});
// 3) Convert back into LatLng.
var nextCornerLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(nextCornerPoint);

var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(
  'path/to/image',
  [originLatLng, nextCornerLatLng]
).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/tehi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This only works at a fixed zoom level. If you zoom out, the pixels cover a bigger area and so the image is bigger